# Which time a constant variable inside a class in php is loaded in RAM when other class uses it?

Tags: php

For example I have class A in file a.php

```
namespace Path\To;
class A {

    const SOME_VAR = 'value';

    // many functions
}
```

And I have class B in file b.php

```
use Path\To\A;
class B {

    public function foo() {

        $i = 1;
        $i = 2;
        $i = 3;
        // other code

       $someVar = A::SOME_VAR;

    }

    // other functions
}
```

Which time in executing function `foo` constant variable `SOME_VAR` loads in RAM. On first line of function foo or on line `$someVar = A::SOME_VAR;` or line `use Path\to\A;` or elsewhere?

Comment: Why do you ask? Or how is it relevant to your problem?

Comment: No problem. I merely want to know this nuance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.php` is read, parsed and executed when `$someVar = A::SOME_VAR;` is executed inside `b.php`. That is also when the `'value'` string is loaded into memory.

At that same time, everything about class `A` is loaded. If you where to add `const SECOND_VAR = 'another-value';` to class `A`, once `$someVar = A::SOME_VAR;` has been executed there is also a bit of RAM that contains `'another-value'`.

What the `use Path\To\A;` line does, is just tell PHP "if class `A` is requested, what they mean is `\Path\To\A`". You can add `use Some\Non\ExistentClass` and `use Some\Class\That\Has\ASyntaxErrorInTheCode`, and nothing will change, because as long as you don't try to actually do anything with `ExistentClass` or `ASyntaxErrorInTheCode` PHP will never read the files that those classes are in.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is being allocated the first time you request the value of the variable. An easy way to test it is the following:

Create a file named Foo.php

```
<?php

class Foo {
    // As of PHP 7.1.0
    public const BAR = 'bar';
    private const BAZ = 'baz';
}
?>
```

Use the following file anywhere you want.

And then type the following 2 lines:

```
$x = FOO::BAR;
$y = FOO::BAZ; // <- this will cause an error, since the variable is private
```

No error will occur during the use of the file, or while retrieving the value of the previous `BAR` variable.
This way you can identify that PHP knows nothing about that variable before you attempt to access its value.